# How can a router port forward and read the destination port if it's a L3 device

Tags: osi, port-forwarding

My understanding of port forwarding is that on the router, you configure a setting that allows you to forward all packets from external traffic with a specific destination port towards a device within your network.

It is also to my understanding that routers are a L3 device, and should only read from the L3 header

Ports are located within L4.

Thus, how is a router able to read the destination port of the incoming packet?

Comment: Remember that the OSI model is just a model, and layers are just an imaginary construct.  Real life isn't so neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on the router, you configure a setting that allows you to forward all packets from external traffic with a specific destination port towards a device within your network.

More specifically, you forward all traffic addressed to the router's public IP address with a specific transport-layer protocol (TCP or UDP) and a specific L4 destination port to a host with a specific private IP address and a (possibly different) destination port. This is also called reverse NAT or destination NAT.

> routers are a L3 device, and should only read from the L3 header. Ports are located within L4.

That is correct.

A *normal* router works on L3 only. A *NAT* (or rather *NAPT*) router however works on both L3 and L4. Also, a normal router is entirely stateless while a NAPT router needs to track "sessions" and translate accordingly.

The distinction between NAT (pure L3 translation) and NAPT (L3/L4 translation) is largely historic. NAPT is far more common today. [edit] As Peter has correctly pointed out, even purely L3 NAT (one-to-one) requires correction of the L4 pseudo header checksum, so it isn't all L3 either.

Comment: Even one to one NAT is not a purely L3 process due to the way checksums work.

Answer (score 0):

> It is also to my understanding that routers are a L3 device

Fundamentally the issue is that there is a disconnect between the functionality of a router as conceived by those who created the internet and the functionality of a commercial device that says "router" on the box.

Routing as originally conceived was and is a layer 3 process. However over the years, equipment sold as "routers" gained additional functionality, such as packet filtering, network address translation. This functionality requires reaching into higher levels of the packet.

Routers aimed at home and small buisiness applications are generally configured by default in a mode where they perform network address translation to hide an entire network of computers behind a single external IP. Port forwarding is a function of the network address translation system allowing connections to be initiated from outside to inside.